# Twig read image height/width attributes

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-2.2

I have an image like so:

```
{% image output='/images/foo.jpg' '@MyBundle/Resources/public/images/bar.jpg' %}
    <img src="{{ asset(asset_url) }}" alt="Something">
{% endimage %}
```

now I would like to get the image dimensions and add width and height attributes like

```
{% image output='/images/foo.jpg' '@MyBundle/Resources/public/images/bar.jpg' %}
    <img src="{{ asset(asset_url) }}" alt="Something" width="{{ asset(asset_width) }}" height="{{ asset(asset_height) }}">
{% endimage %}
```

Is this possible?

Best Regards

Answer (score -2):

In your controller, do

```
return $this->render(
    'assetic'  => array(
        'vars'  => array(
            'height'  => '300px',
            'width'  => '400px'
        )
);
```

Then in your twig template

```
{% image vars=['height', 'width'] output='/images/foo.jpg?{height}x{width}' '@MyBundle/Resources/public/images/bar.jpg' %}
    <img src="{{ asset(asset_url) }}" alt="Something" height="{{assetic.vars.height}}" width="{{assetic.vars.width}}">
{% endimage %}
```

The only limitation/problem with this approach is, you need to include the dynamic variables (height and width) in the output url.

Do let us know how it went

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for your Response, first I get


`[ErrorException]                                                                                                                   
  Notice: Undefined index: height in /mypath/vendor/kriswallsmith/assetic/src/Assetic/Util/VarUtils.php line 71`

But I think this isn't really what I'm looking for. With your approach I can set a specific width and height - what I'm looking for is _getting_ the images width and height to pass it to the browser, so the page is not re-rendered when the image is loaded.

Comment: I am sorry, I couldn't get time to respond . . . are you still looking for a solution?

Comment: Sure, I would still be glad to have one ;-)